# Unsolved entanglement problems

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

What are the current most important *theoretical* problems on quantum entanglement?
What is that we don't yet understand about how it works?
(Not considering interpretation etc problems)

Comment: Why is this question a community wiki ?

Comment: I think this is usual when one expects a list of examples instead of a specific answer to a specific question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see two current main axis of research around entanglement. I have not really followed the last years of research, so I don't know exactly which questions are open and which have been solved.

I sadly have no time to elaborate this week, but since its a community wiki, others can complete my answer.

**Entanglement characterization**

The question is on how to characterize entanglement as a resource and how to interconvert various entanglement form into others. While the problem has essentially been solved for two-party-entanglement, many open question subsists in n-party-entanglement.

For a recent technical review, you can read the Horodecki family paper in Review of Modern Physics [(restricted access)](http://rmp.aps.org/abstract/RMP/v81/i2/p865_1) [(arXiv version)](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0702225).

**Finding quantum physics from information theoretic consideration**

It is well known that quantum entanglement does not allow any faster than light communication. This is called the "no-signalling" principle. However, the no-signalling principle does not forbids theories with stronger correlations than quantum mechanical entanglement (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlocality#Generalising_nonlocality).) It has been shown that if one could build such a "super-entangled" machine, one could perform various unintuitive communication-complexity related tasks (see [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0501159v1) and [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/0905.2292) for technical papers about this, and [here](http://scienceblogs.com/pontiff/2009/05/information_causality.php) and [here](http://complementaryslackness.wordpress.com/2009/06/01/information-causality/) for blog posts about the second paper). The interesting open question is the following: can we find all the quantum-entanglement correlations (and the quantum mechanics formalism) from reasonable information-theoretic constraints similar to the no-signaling principle.

Answer (score -1):

quantum entanglement is a basic property of multi-body quantum mechanics - or any quantum mechanics with at least two degrees of freedom - that has been understood from the mid 1920s. So for 85 years, there have been no open theoretical problems related to quantum entanglement and it has been understood *that* it works as well as *how* any doable experiment involving entanglement works even though the modern terminology related to quantum information has only been used for a few decades.

Sincerely
Luboš

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a point asking the same question for problems *related* to quantum entanglement?

Comment: I beg to differ on your sentence on"for 85 years, there have been no open theoretical problems related to quantum entanglement" . There are open problems in multi-partite entanglement, entanglement witnesses, and bound entanglement, to name a few problems which are not only terminology related.

Comment: This answer is simply incorrect. Anyone who thinks there are no open problems in quantum entanglement has not been keeping up with developments in quantum information and quantum computation.

Comment: I didn't write there were no problems. I wrote that there were no theoretical problems. There are of course engineering problems - to sustain entanglement for a lot of time (to get quantum computers) and to solve particular algorithmic and other problems to make the machinery more useful. But these are applied physics and information technology problems, not theoretical problems.

Comment: @Lubos I'm sure you know the weight your words have. You can see this from the first comment where @Eelvex says: "Is there a point asking the same question for problems related to quantum entanglement?" What do you mean by a "theoretical problem"? Newton's laws of motion were put forward in the 17th century. Yet mechanics was in fervent till the 19th century. Entanglement is a notion. Our understanding of this notion evolves only when we consider problems involving it. It is incorrect to say that there are no theoretical problems involving entanglement.

Comment: Dear space_cadet, I wasn't the person who introduced the adjective "theoretical" to the problems. Eelvex, the very Gentleman who asked the question, asked about *theoretical* problems, and to be sure, he emphasized the word "theoretical" by italics just like I did in this very sentence. Theoretical problems related to XY are problem

Comment: ...are problems about why the XY exists and how any effect or phenomenon related to or caused by XY may be predicted, at least in principle with a good knowledge of maths. All these problems were solved since the 1920s which is why there are no open theoretical physics problems surrouding entanglement. The open problems are engineering and mathematical ones, not theoretical ones. You may check that all the "open problems" on this page are either (hopeless) attempts to revise the basic structure of quantum mechanics, or engineering "software conversion"-like problems.

Comment: @Luboš : According to your definition, there have been not theoretical problem in classical mechanics avter Newton, and all the development of the notion of energy, action and Hamiltonian mechanics in 19th century are maths without any theory ?

Comment: I am puzzled as to why this has any down votes. The question states exactly: "What is that we don't yet understand about **how it works**?" and the answer is, exactly, "we understand everything about **how it works**."  We do not understand everything about *its consequences*, as Lubos said, there are lots of interesting applications and examples we don't know of yet, but those are two **opposite** sides of a logical implication!  If people can't tell those apart, then there's a problem...

Comment: @Frédéric: of course, the statement you attribute to me - even though I didn't write it - is true. The development of the Hamiltonian and Lagrangian mechanics wasn't a solution to any "open problem" in classical physics - because there hadn't been any. They were just new formalisms to describe the same physics, and they consequently offered no answers that would be impossible to obtain previously. From the viewpoint of actual problems and their solutions, the new notions of action, Hamiltonian etc. were just maths or formalisms without new physical theories.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Jeremy. And exactly: the question specifically asked about *theoretical* problems, with the italics fonts, so any problems related to complicated applications are automatically removed as a part of a legitimate answer. This answer of mine is my worst down-voted answer among 463 answers I have written on this server. But I am not going to erase it because I still consider it true and appropriate as an answer to the question as it was asked. Of course, it is not a problem to have two answers with negative totals. ;-)

Comment: By the way, the number of votes is not "statistically large" but it could be. What's the reason people don't like such answers? I think that there is some quasi-religious tendency to celebrate entanglement as an ultimate mystery that can't ever be matched by the mortal humans and whose true physics surely has to be totally different than QM. However, entanglement is just a generic fact about QM - most states are not tensor products - and nothing has changed (or will change) about those basic structures on the Hilbert space from 1925. The fundamental theory of entanglement is fully understood.

Comment: @Luboš Motl : OK I think we clearly not agree on what a "theoretical" problem is, but it is not really relevant, since we agree on the scientific facts. I'm thinking about writing a synthesis of both our answers in order to show that there is no real opposition, but I'm really not sure I'll have the time.